# Tags that are listed in the 'New' section

Tags: discussion, tags

As of today 02/16/17, I found a tag [strip-map](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/strip-map) listed in the [new section on page 2](https://gis.stackexchange.com/tags?page=2&tab=new)

[image]

When I checked, the history of question for this tag, [there are questions that date back to 2013](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/strip-map)

How is it that the strip-map tag appears in the new section of the tags, while having question dating back to 2013?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Although the tag appears on old questions, it appears these questions have been edited since the [strip-map](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/strip-map) tag was created.  These edits added the new tag onto the old questions.

This question which was asked in 2013 was modified on Jan 17 2017:
[image]

The edit was to remove one tag and add the new one:
[image]